# Facebook Share in iframe

Tags: html, facebook

Have you seen an implementation of [Facebook Share](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Implementing_Facebook_Share) where the confirmation appears not in a new window but in a iframe or a div? How can I do that?

It is not for a Facebook application or [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Facebook_Connect), but for a normal blog that has a "share" button.

Like this: (thanks sarfraz)

[image]
<sub>(source: [widgetbox.com](http://blog.widgetbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/facebook-connect-comments-part-2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, that is not Facebook Share, it is stream publishing dialog, more on that here:

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/04/28/first-look-publishing-data-to-the-facebook-stream-using-the-new-stream-apis/